# CSS : z-index and hover

Tags: css, user-interface

I have a html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<div class="maindiv"><div class="subdiv"><input type="submit" class="button" value="button"/></div></div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And the test.css file :

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.maindiv {
position:relative;
}
.subdiv {
position:relative;
}
.button:hover {
background-color:#333;
}
```

Everything was working fine till now. Bg of the button changes color if mouse is over the button.

I added z-index=-1 for the subdiv.

```
.subdiv {
position:relative;
z-index:-1;
}
```

After which hover was not working. So i used Firefox Inspector tool to capture the element when mouse is over the button  and it was capturing 'div.maindiv'.
So i thought of adding z-index=-2 for the maindiv after which it was capturing 'body'

Can some one tell me why it is happening?

Comment: Why do you need to set the z-index to -1? Here's a jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2fZN/2/

Comment: I have an element inside div which should be partially above the subdiv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any specific reason you are adding `z-index: -1` to the `subdiv` element? Because, adding  that to the `subdiv` is going to place it 'below' the `maindiv` and body and you wont be able to click on it as a result. The `maindiv` will cover it so the hover and click event will be not captured by `subdiv`.

Similarly, making `maindiv` have `z-index: -2` will cause the `body` element to cover it in the stacking order and therefore again the button will not be clicked.

If you give the `body` element a `position: relative; z-index: -3;`, then the button can be clicked by the above logic.

From [w3 schools z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

> The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
>
> An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Check out [this](http://timkadlec.com/2008/01/detailed-look-at-stacking-in-css/) link as well for more on z-index.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. can you tell me what is the significance of giving position:relative here.

Comment: You're welcome! Position is just a way of 'positioning' the html element on the page. z-index has meaning only if the element is 'positioned' (meaning absolute, relative or fixed). Position: relative means that the element is positioned relative to where it would have been normally (as rendered in the order of document flow).